# Ember Select View accessing controller model

Tags: ember.js

I have an array of items and I want to have a select view for each of the item in the array. I am able to populate the dropdown list, but i am unable to set the default select value for each of the item.

```
{{#each item in items}}
    {{item.item_name}}{{item.user_id}}
    {{view Ember.Select 
         content=controller.users
         optionValuePath="content.user_id"
         optionLabelpath="content.user_name"
         value="item.user_id"}}
{{/each}}
```

Each item object contains a user_id. I want the select view for each item to be set in accordance to the user_id from each item.

Thanks!

Comment: try: `{{view Ember.Select 
         contentBinding=controller.users
         optionValuePath="content.id"
         optionLabelPath="content.user_name"
         valueBinding="item.user_id"}}`

Comment: Hey Surya, changing from value to valueBinding solved the problem! Thank you so much!

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you. Posted as answer so someone with the same problem in future can locate the solution easily. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, `optionLabelPath` was not correct and `optionValuePath="content.user_id"` should have been `optionValuePath="content.id"` also the `value` should be `valueBinding`.

Something like this:

```
{{view Ember.Select
                   contentBinding=controller.users
                   optionValuePath="content.id"
                   optionLabelPath="content.user_name"
                   valueBinding="item.user_id"}}
```

Comment: It is considered marginally better style to say `value=item.user_id`.